# Iterate over a Vector with condition and return the second item of Vector/Tuple

Tags: loops, rust, vector

Despite the numerous examples on internet I could not figure out this one:

How to iterate over a Vector (which itself contains Vector of 2 String items) and return the second item?

My attempt (returns `true`, I would like to get `"the result"` instead)

```
fn main() {
     let data:Vec<Vec<&str>> = vec![vec!["b", "dummy"], vec!["c", "dummy"],vec!["r", "the result"], vec!["a", "dummy"]];
     let a = data.iter().any(|i| i.into_iter().nth(0).unwrap() == &"r");
     println!("{}",a);
}
```

Also I would like to **consume the vector and avoid unnecessary copy**, as well as **stop at the first result** (or when reaching end of vector if no result).

NB: I know that the inside Vector could be a tuple but I don't have control over this type of data as it is returned to me as a Vector by an API.

Comment: You don't need an expensive copy if the data is `&str`. But is it really `&str`, or `String`?

Comment: `data.into_iter().next().flat_map (|v| v.drain().skip (1).next())`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman it is a JsonValue actually (axum crate) which looks like "String("myString"), I can convert it to either &str or string I think

Comment: @Jmb I have simplified the array, it contains thousands of values, so I am not aiming at a precise position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`any()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.any) is the wrong tool for the job. The correct tool is [`find()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.find):

```rust
let a: Option<&str> = data
    .iter()
    .find(|inner_vec| inner_vec[0] == "r")
    .map(|inner_vec| inner_vec[1]);
println!("{:?}", a);
```

If you have `String`s in the vectors and not `&str`, and you want to avoid cloning, it is just a bit more complicated:

```rust
let a: Option<String> = data
    .into_iter()
    .find(|inner_vec| inner_vec[0] == "r")
    .and_then(|inner_vec| inner_vec.into_iter().nth(1));
println!("{:?}", a);
```

Comment: Terrific, thank you!

Comment: Alternatively, `data.iter().find_map(|inner_vec| (inner_vec[0] == "r").then_some(inner_vec[1]))`

Comment: @BallpointBen Yeah, this is also a possibility. I prefer `find().map()` when the condition and the returned value are unrelated, but this is subjective.

Comment: Thanks @BallpointBen , Would either make a difference once compiled in release mode?

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL @BallpointBen's approach evaluates the element to be returned even for other elements, but the compiler can optimize it away. Or you can use `.then(||` to prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution w/o mapping and 2nd iteration:

```
if let Some(a) = data.iter().find(|x| x[0] == ["r"][0]) {
    println!("{:?}", a.get(1));
};
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=57eada46bb59e92242e7d69ebb7394ff)